# Symfony Form howto automaticly set parent on child

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

On my formType I added another subform

```
    // ParentFormType
    $builder->add('children', 'collection', array(
        'type' => new ChildFormType(),
        'prototype'    => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'allow_add' => true,
    ));

    // ChildFormType
    $builder->add('age', 'text', array(
        'required' => true));
```

When I try to save the form to foreach the childs and set the parent, is there a way to **avoid this foreach**.

```
    $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    /** This foreach I want to avoid */
    foreach ($parent->getChildren() as $child) {
        $child->setParent($parent);
    }
    $em->persist($parent);
    $em->flush();
```

Here is the ORM-XML from Parent:

```
    <one-to-many field="children" target-entity="Client\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Entity\Children" mapped-by="parent">
        <cascade>
            <cascade-persist />
        </cascade>
    </one-to-many>
```

Here is the ORM-XML from Parent:

```
    <many-to-one field="parent" target-entity="Client\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Entity\Parent" inversed-by="children">
        <join-columns>
            <join-column name="idParents" referenced-column-name="id" on-delete="CASCADE" nullable="false" />
        </join-columns>
    </many-to-one>
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Koalabaerchen's answer, in order to let handleRequest call the addChild method on the parent entity you should set by_reference to false (see [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference)):

```
// ParentFormType
$builder->add('children', 'collection', array(
    ...
    'by_reference' => false,
));
```

Answer (score 2):

In the setter in the entity of the parent you can do something like

```
 public function addChild(Child $children)
    {
        $this->children->add($children);
        $children->setParent($this);

        return $this;
    }
```

Now everytime you add a child to the entity (which happens with the collection) it also sets the parent inside the child.

Comment: I did try it but addChild seems not to be called by the symfony forms strange behaviour.

Comment: The form doesn't call that. You should call it manually or refresh the entity trough the EntityManager

Comment: @AlexanderSchranz http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

Comment: this is what I wanted to avoid doing it manually in the controller.

Comment: You have to persist your stuff somewhere. And CRUD functions are supposed to be in crontrollers. You can avoid the foreach if you go through handlerequest. In the link above inside the if you just persist the entity and it will be written to the database. Even to the child.